# Youtube Api, Get video url with given id channel and title of video

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api

I need id of video for example 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIN0tTy-Jmg

the id which I need is wIN0tTy-Jmg

I know about
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.activities.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCuaCWszD8Z2bZcSNvlAR6UA&maxResults=50&fields=items(snippet(thumbnails%252Fdefault%252Ctitle))&_h=14&

but it returns only 50 videos and sometimes I can't get video which has title that I need

I need only one video id, I know title and given channel ID

How to get this id? Any ideas?

Comment: Is it your video?

Comment: yes it is my video

Answer (score 0):

The youtube api does not have a video get method. So there is no way to directly get just a single video.

I am not sure why you are using the activites.list method.

I would use a [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) and send the channel id. [example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCWnY0GoKFnFY0oeaEN605Ug&maxResults=50&_h=3&)

**request**

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCWnY0GoKFnFY0oeaEN605Ug&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

**response**

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/9HyOjSMVnKv1vm239plm060CuiY\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
 "regionCode": "DK",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 71,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 ...

}
```

It is still returning more then the max 50 rows.  You are going to have to use the next page token to get the next page of results.

Answer (score 0):

The video url is not direct in the response, but you can get is since the thunbnail url has the part you need. Eg:

'thumbnails': {'default': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k6MAcJLxE1I/default.jpg', ...

actual video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6MAcJLxE1I

so, when you get the response from the playlist, the url will be

'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + response["items"][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']["standard"]["url"].split("/")[-2]

where 0 is the first video of the list and so on